# SDP status shows that one document was skipped, but the *_OVERFLOW table is empty

Tags: cloudant, cloudant-sdp

I am running the SDP to export some data from Cloudant to dashDB.

The SDP status shows that one document is skipped, but the `*_OVERFLOW` table is empty.

[image]

Questions:

1. What does 'skipped' actually mean? What is the difference between **skipped** and **error**?
2. How can I debug to find out which document was skipped?
3. How can I debug to find out why the document was skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDP skips any document where the document identifier starts with '_', such as design documents, attachments, view definitions etc.

These *special* documents are excluded during discovery and load and there is no mention of them in the `OVERFLOW` table.

For all other documents the SDP load can result in:

1. a successful load (no record in the `OVERFLOW` table)
2. a successful load but with a warning in the `OVERFLOW` table
3. a failed load and error message in the `OVERFLOW` table

The `OVERFLOW` table contains the document identifier for every warning and error.